# How to trigger resize event using nvd3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I need to now how to trigger the resize event on nvd3 for AngularJS.

The problem is that I have made line breaks on the labels within the piechart and when I resize the window, the labels return to their original state(1 line).

And I want it to break the line every time it triggers the resize event.

This is my **html**:

```
<nvd3 on-ready="ctrl.onReadyPie('id')" options='ctrl.pieChartOptions' data='ctrl.data'>
</nvd3>
```

The function `onReadyPie` makes the line breaks:

```
function onReadyPie(id){            
    var svg = d3.selectAll('#' + id + ' svg g text');
    svg.each(function(){
        var el = d3.select(this),
            lines = el.html().split(' / ');
        el.text('');
        for(var i = 0; i<lines.length; i++){
            var tspan = el.append('tspan').text(lines[i]);
            if(i>0){
                tspan.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', 15);
            }
         }
     })
}
```

[This is the current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjMfv.png)

Comment: Please post a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok William already update the question with the code:)

Comment: You should use [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) instead of a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can trigger an event when the window resizes using NVD3.

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
  // You chart properties goes here

  // Detect window resize using NVD3
  nv.utils.windowResize(function(){ chart.update(); });

  return chart;
});
```

For more information check the [NVD3 wiki](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/wiki).

Hope it helps